# Problems aligning text in a table

Tags: tables, errors

I am having problems with a table.

It seems that I am unable to align my table correctly. The text between the second and third row should be aligned; also the text is very close to the top bar. Is there an easy fix to this problem?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

 \begin{document}


 \begin{table*}[ht]\centering
 \begin{tabular}{  l  l  l  l  l  l  l  l  } \hline
 \ & \ & \ Yellow conidia & \  & \  & \ & Black conidia  \  & \  \\ \hline
 \ & Yield  & Yield & OD Reference \ & \ & Yield  & Yield & OD Reference  \  \\
 Run & (ng/uL) &  ($\mu$g/g of conidia) & (260/280) & Run & (ng/uL) &  ($\mu$g/g of conidia) & (260/280) \\ \hline
 1 & 685 & 1370 & 2.04 & 1 & 377.5 & 754.9 & 1.98 \\ 
 2 & 186.7 & 373.4 & 1.71 & 2 & 122.6 & 245.2 & 1.6 \\ 
 3 & 314.1 & 628.2 & 1.81 & 3 & 387.2 & 774.4 & 2.04 \\ 
 4 & 209.1 & 418.2 & 1.84 & 4 & 291.3 & 582.7 & 1.92 \\ 
 5 & 724.3 & 1448.5 & 1.99 & 5 & 615.5 & 1231 & 1.99 \\ 
 6 & 582.7 & 1165.3 & 1.74 & 6 & 337.4 & 674.9 & 2.09 \\ 
 7 & 334.4 & 668.7 & 2.00 & 7 & 282 & 564 & 2.04 \\ 
 8 & 126 & 252 & 2.13 & 8 & 92.8 & 185.6 & 1.99 \\ 
 9 & 647.1 & 1294.2 & 1.95 & 9 & 507.6 & 1015.2 & 1.99 \\ 
10 & 964.4 & 1928.8 & 2.06 & 10 & 508 & 1016 & 1.87 \\
11 & 1033.9 & 2067.8 & 1.92 & 11 & 760.9 & 1521.8 & 1.92 \\ 
12 & 439 & 877.9 & 1.88 & 12 & 368.6 & 737.1 & 1.88 \\ 
13 & 1242.7 & 2485.4 & 1.88 & 13 & 911.2 & 1822.4 & 1.93 \\ 
14 & 1113 & 2226 & 1.82 & 14 & 283.7 & 567.4 & 1.56 \\ 
15 & 1081.7 & 2163.4 & 1.93 & 15 & 575.9 & 1151.8 & 1.92 \\ 
16 & 274.3 & 548.6 & 1.87 & 16 & 151.3 & 302.6 & 1.79 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) Always post full minimal examples, i.e. including documentclass and preamble (makes it more likely you will get help). (2) What exactly does not align? Looks fine to me. Though I would align the decimals

Comment: as daleif says you should post a complete document but also get rid of all the `\ ` in the first two rows which are either doing nothing or breaking the left alignment, depending where they are.

Comment: sorry new to this, but the text i wish to align is yield and have (ng/ul) aligned below.. or is this not the correct method ?

Comment: We can not see the output as your fragment can  not be processed, it looks like they ought both to be left aligned in their cell, but if you posted code that could be processed it would be easier to debug

Comment: `SelfArx` class is presumably some private code. please use `article` (and check that the problem occurs with article) it's hard to help you if you post code we can't use.

Comment: thanks for all the replies, @David Carlisle yes i am using a template in writelatex. i change the document in my post, it is give the same output - well now the table it self is skewed to the right of the document. text in 2-3 row are still not align on top of each other

Answer (score 4):

[image]

still a fraction over-full but...

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{dcolumn,booktabs}
\begin{document}

  \begin{table}\centering
  \begin{tabular}{   *{2}{D..{2.0} D..{4.1} D..{4.1} D..{1.2}}}
\toprule
&
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Yellow conidia}&
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Black conidia} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Run} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{1.3cm}}{\centering Yield\\ (ng/uL)}&
\multicolumn{1}{p{1.3cm}}{\centering Yield\\  ($\mu$g/g of conidia)}&
\multicolumn{1}{p{1.3cm}}{\centering OD Reference  \\ (260/280)}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Run} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{1.3cm}}{\centering Yield\\ (ng/uL)}&
\multicolumn{1}{p{1.3cm}}{\centering Yield\\  ($\mu$g/g of conidia)}&
\multicolumn{1}{p{1.3cm}}{\centering OD Reference  \\ (260/280)}\\
\midrule
  1 & 685 & 1370 & 2.04 & 1 & 377.5 & 754.9 & 1.98 \\
  2 & 186.7 & 373.4 & 1.71 & 2 & 122.6 & 245.2 & 1.6 \\
  3 & 314.1 & 628.2 & 1.81 & 3 & 387.2 & 774.4 & 2.04 \\
  4 & 209.1 & 418.2 & 1.84 & 4 & 291.3 & 582.7 & 1.92 \\
  5 & 724.3 & 1448.5 & 1.99 & 5 & 615.5 & 1231 & 1.99 \\
  6 & 582.7 & 1165.3 & 1.74 & 6 & 337.4 & 674.9 & 2.09 \\
  7 & 334.4 & 668.7 & 2.00 & 7 & 282 & 564 & 2.04 \\
  8 & 126 & 252 & 2.13 & 8 & 92.8 & 185.6 & 1.99 \\
  9 & 647.1 & 1294.2 & 1.95 & 9 & 507.6 & 1015.2 & 1.99 \\
  10 & 964.4 & 1928.8 & 2.06 & 10 & 508 & 1016 & 1.87 \\\\
  11 & 1033.9 & 2067.8 & 1.92 & 11 & 760.9 & 1521.8 & 1.92 \\
  12 & 439 & 877.9 & 1.88 & 12 & 368.6 & 737.1 & 1.88 \\
  13 & 1242.7 & 2485.4 & 1.88 & 13 & 911.2 & 1822.4 & 1.93 \\
  14 & 1113 & 2226 & 1.82 & 14 & 283.7 & 567.4 & 1.56 \\
  15 & 1081.7 & 2163.4 & 1.93 & 15 & 575.9 & 1151.8 & 1.92 \\
  16 & 274.3 & 548.6 & 1.87 & 16 & 151.3 & 302.6 & 1.79 \\
\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: how would you spred out the table from margin to margin ?

Comment: @Strangelove just increase the 1.3cm a bit if there is room, mainly i was shrinking it to fit rather than expand it:-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that uses (a) the `S` column type of the `siunitx` to align the numerical entries on the decimal markers, (b) the `\si` macro (also of the `siunitx` package) to format the units, and (c) the `tabularx` package (and a modified form of that package's `X` column type for 6 of the 8 subheaders) to force the table to occupy the full width (and no more!) of the textblock. Finally, the rule-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package are used to obtain good spacing around the horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
  \sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
  \newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered form of "X" column type
  \newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}        % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt} % default value: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{2}{l *{2}{S[table-format=4.1]} S[table-format=1.2]}  @{}} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}c}{Yellow conidia} & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Black conidia} \\ 
\cmidrule(r){1-4} \cmidrule(l){5-8}
%% use "C" column type for six of the eight header cells
Run & \mC{Yield (\si{\nano\gram\per\micro\liter})} 
    & \mC{Yield (\si{\micro\gram\per\gram} of conidia)} 
    & \mC{OD Reference (260/280)} &
Run & \mC{Yield (\si{\nano\gram\per\micro\liter})} 
    & \mC{Yield (\si{\micro\gram\per\gram} of conidia)} 
    & \mC{OD Reference (260/280)}\\
\midrule
 1 & 685 & 1370 & 2.04 & 1 & 377.5 & 754.9 & 1.98 \\ 
 2 & 186.7 & 373.4 & 1.71 & 2 & 122.6 & 245.2 & 1.6 \\ 
 3 & 314.1 & 628.2 & 1.81 & 3 & 387.2 & 774.4 & 2.04 \\ 
 4 & 209.1 & 418.2 & 1.84 & 4 & 291.3 & 582.7 & 1.92 \\ 
 5 & 724.3 & 1448.5 & 1.99 & 5 & 615.5 & 1231 & 1.99 \\ 
 6 & 582.7 & 1165.3 & 1.74 & 6 & 337.4 & 674.9 & 2.09 \\ 
 7 & 334.4 & 668.7 & 2.00 & 7 & 282 & 564 & 2.04 \\ 
 8 & 126 & 252 & 2.13 & 8 & 92.8 & 185.6 & 1.99 \\ 
 9 & 647.1 & 1294.2 & 1.95 & 9 & 507.6 & 1015.2 & 1.99 \\ 
10 & 964.4 & 1928.8 & 2.06 & 10 & 508 & 1016 & 1.87 \\
11 & 1033.9 & 2067.8 & 1.92 & 11 & 760.9 & 1521.8 & 1.92 \\ 
12 & 439 & 877.9 & 1.88 & 12 & 368.6 & 737.1 & 1.88 \\ 
13 & 1242.7 & 2485.4 & 1.88 & 13 & 911.2 & 1822.4 & 1.93 \\ 
14 & 1113 & 2226 & 1.82 & 14 & 283.7 & 567.4 & 1.56 \\ 
15 & 1081.7 & 2163.4 & 1.93 & 15 & 575.9 & 1151.8 & 1.92 \\ 
16 & 274.3 & 548.6 & 1.87 & 16 & 151.3 & 302.6 & 1.79 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, is it the sisetup that allows you to write micro\gram\per\gram ?

Comment: @Strangelove - Yes. I'll amend the writeup to include this bit of information.